# Rails3 Devise authentication Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, authentication, rails-migrations

I have been messing around with how it will be best for my new application to represent the users table in the database.

I noticed a migration named like this:

```
20110512234640_devise_create_users.rb
```

Is that something that Device creates upon its install?  Or can I just use a simpler users table migration that I'd write by hand?

How do people usually configure Devise and still be able to add on extra columns to the users table which their particular applications might need?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you can create on more migration to add your own fields to Devise used table (this is to keep devise migration clear and simple)

Comment: That is a good point.  But the file that I mentioned in my question is definitely something that Devise auto-generates, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it is an automatically generated migration by Devise which allows you to choose your Devise modules more easily since default modules are added to the migration and others are there too but commented.

Of course, you can use a written-by-hand user migration.

Personally, I use that generated migration to add my own extra fields. But using a custom user migration file is the same.